# Wired keyboard and mouse not working anymore

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse

I recently upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and other than TwinView problems it seemed to be working. While trying to fix the TwinView issues, I rebooted the computer and the keyboard and mouse no longer worked.

I can hit <kbd>F12</kbd> during boot to pick boot device but once the login screen hits neither work. When I `ssh` into the machine, `lsusb` shows that both the keyboard and mouse are seen.

Any suggestions on getting them working?

After looking in the Xorg.0.log file I see this.

```
[    60.280] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Optical USB Mouse (/dev/input/event2)  
[    60.280] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.  
[    60.280] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.  
[    60.280] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Optical USB Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)  
[    60.280] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.  
[    60.280] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.  
[    60.280] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell Dell QuietKey Keyboard (/dev/input/event3)  
[    60.280] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.  
[    60.280] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this archlinux bug may be the same issue:  https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/33606

If that's the case, then it's fixed by kernel version 3.7.4.  I haven't yet tried it - I'm currently huntingfor a solution myself, but this looks promising once I figure out how to install the later kernel.

I've also had problems with a USB keyboard, but less so.

I find that while the USB mouse is usually not working when I come out of hibernation, it often is working if I try it later in the day (it's usually left plugged in).